# Visa requirements for rechecking luggage in Frankfurt Airport

Tags: visas, schengen, luggage

I am a citizen of Turkey and hold a US visa. I will be traveling from US to Turkey with layovers in Iceland and Germany. I need to get my luggage in Frankfurt Airport and recheck it. Normally, I don't need a transit visa for Germany since I hold a US visa, but I have never had to recheck my luggage before. What kind of documentation do I need to reach the luggage area and connect to the final leg of my flight?

Comment: If your only nationality is Turkish, you're going to need a full Schengen visa for this journey.  Your US visa won't help.  It's not about your luggage, it's the fact that the flight from Iceland to Germany is "domestic" and you have to enter Iceland in order to take it.  This is not a transit situation anymore.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you have to enter Iceland in order to take it"? What is "it"? @NateEldredge

Comment: "It" is your flight from Iceland to Germany.

Comment: @NateEldredge but even without the internal flight, for example flying directly from the US to Frankfurt and from there directly to Turkey, having to get the luggage in Frankfurt would require a "regular" Schengen visa.

Comment: This itinerary requires a regular short-stay Schengen visa. If you haven't got one, and are not able to obtain one, choose a different flight itinerary.

Comment: What about https://imgur.com/a/F3oRirE? Do you think they ignored the fact that my flight from Iceland to Germany counts as domestic?

Comment: you are not _transiting_! You would be _entering_ Schengen area, and taking a flight within Schengen area. There are no immigration controls on the Iceland-Frankfurt flight and you could walk out in Frankfurt and stay there.

Comment: An airport transit visa is a very specific visa required for citizens of certain countries even if they stay airside (in the “international zone” of the airport) without even going through border control. Here, you **will** be going through border control, for two reasons: because you are boarding an internal flight, and because you need to reclaim and re-check your bags. So you need a **regular** short-stay visa in any case (**not** an airport transit visa).

Comment: Also, unrelated, I hope you have plenty of time in Frankfurt: you will have to drop your checked bags before the check-in deadline (usually one hour), so that means an absolute minimum of about 2 hours, and since the two tickets are booked separately, any delay on the inbound flights means **you** are liable for changes to the last leg (which often means buying a new ticket at last-minute prices), so you should have at the very least 4 hours, possibly a lot more if you don’t want to take any risk.

Comment: Also check that you don’t have to reclaim and recheck your luggage in Reykjavik as well. Some airlines (especially low cost carriers) don’t do through-ticketing even if the two flights are on the same airline. If that were the case, the same recommendation would apply (count a **lot** of time between the flights).

Answer (score 5):

If, as I assume, you have a layover in both Germany and Iceland, the flight between them is an internal Schengen flight and to take it you will have to enter the Schengen zone on a short term visitor visa. And if you travel back the same way, you will need two of them or a multiple entry visa.

Even to just leave the international transfer area in Frankfurt you will need a Schengen visa, as there is no transit visa that will allow you to get your luggage and re-check it. And again the same for the way back if you fly the same route.

If you have not yet bought the tickets, better look at a different route. If you have just one stop in the Schengen zone and do not need to leave the international zone, you can indeed travel without having to get a Schengen visa.

And from your description of the flights, I assume you have two different tickets, where the second airline is not bound to get you to your destination if your first flight is delayed. If so, you will need a long layover, so you will not miss your second flight if you are delayed on the way in, you need more time to pass through immigration and security and such.

You can check details for needed visa on the same database airlines use, Timatic, this is the [IATA site](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) there are more airline related sites as well.

More information about intra Schengen flights and their visa can be found [in the answers to this question.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)